# How to print concatenated string a result of each for loop iteration in R

Tags: r, for-loop

This code words as intended in Python:

```
my_books = ['R','Python','SQL','Java','C']

cou = 0
for i in my_books:
    cou = cou + 1
    print('Book Number:',cou,'&','Name of the book:',i)
print('\nNo more books in the shelf')
```

Output is:

```
Book Number: 1 & Name of the book: R
Book Number: 2 & Name of the book: Python
Book Number: 3 & Name of the book: SQL
Book Number: 4 & Name of the book: Java
Book Number: 5 & Name of the book: C

No more books in the shelf
```

Whereas in R, how to get the same output?
My code in R as below:

```
my_books = c('R','Python','SQL','Java','C')

cou = 0
for(i in my_books){
  cou = cou + 1
  paste('Book Number:',cou,'&','Name of the book:',i)
}
print('No more books in the shelf')
```

The output I get is:
    [1] "No more books in the shelf"

Is there a different function to use within a for loop?

Comment: Is there a reason why we need to use paste inside a print function in a loop?
In this code it works fine as a standalone:
    weather_report <- function(Cel = as.numeric(readline('Enter the temperature 
    in C:'))){
      F = Cel*1.8 + 32
      if(F > 90){
        ans <- 'It\'s too hot'
        print(ans)
      } else{
        ans <- 'It\'s not too hot'
        print(ans)
      }
      paste('Temperature in F =',F)
    }

Comment: If you need to concatenate different objects together you need to use `paste` and since it does not automatically print in `for` loop, you need to explicitly mention that as well. In the function above there is no `for` loop, hence `paste` works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to `print` the `paste` part as it is in the loop. In loop you have to explicitly tell to `print` the things.

```
my_books = c('R','Python','SQL','Java','C')

cou = 0
for(i in my_books){
  cou = cou + 1
  print(paste('Book Number:',cou,'&','Name of the book:',i))
}


#[1] "Book Number: 1 & Name of the book: R"
#[1] "Book Number: 2 & Name of the book: Python"
#[1] "Book Number: 3 & Name of the book: SQL"
#[1] "Book Number: 4 & Name of the book: Java"
#[1] "Book Number: 5 & Name of the book: C"
```

However, let me show you the magic of R. You can avoid the loop by doing

```
paste('Book Number:', seq_along(my_books), '& Name of the book:', my_books)

#[1] "Book Number: 1 & Name of the book: R"     
#[2] "Book Number: 2 & Name of the book: Python"
#[3] "Book Number: 3 & Name of the book: SQL"   
#[4] "Book Number: 4 & Name of the book: Java"  
#[5] "Book Number: 5 & Name of the book: C"
```